# 2 Layer Tilemaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.5

I'm making a tile-based game in pygame and everything is working :) but I want  to be able to have 2 or 3 layer tilemaps. Unfortunately, I'm relatively new to working with tilemaps and don't know how I would go about doing this. Right now, I have a file maps.py which can load and draw maps. These maps are in the folder /maps/, and each of the maps have their own folder, like /resto/ or /countryside/. Inside here are two files -- map.png and config.ini. The config.ini looks like this:

```
[level]
tileset = map.png
tilesize = 32
mapstring = @.......@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
            @(.....)@.....................................................@
            @(.....)@.....................................................@
            @(.....)@...({}).......({})......({}).......({}).......({})...@
            @(.....)@...(/\).......(/\)......(/\).......(/\).......(/\)...@
            @(.....)@.....................................................@
            etc...
tiles = .@()/\{}

[.]
name = floor
pos = 0, 0
wall = False

[@]
name = wall
pos = 3, 0
wall = True

[(]
name = lChair
pos = 0, 1
wall = False

more tiles...
```

I'm wondering how I can change this (and, obviously, maps.py. But that part I think I can do without SO) to support 2+ layer maps.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `mapstring_layer1`, `mapstring_layer2`, etc.

Comment: @furas That worked perfectly! If you want, you can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define every layer as separated string: `mapstring_layer1`, `mapstring_layer2`, etc.
They will be more readable for you and easy to code.

And you could add variable with number of layers `layers = 2`